# Porqué obtengo este error en un método: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `class` en **python 3**. Escribí un código hace un tiempo y decidí transformarlo a clases y me encuentro varado con este error:

> ```
> <ipython-input-67-42b4fc5729b3> in savage(self)
>      11         list1 = list()
>      12         while i < len(self.Acciones):
> ---> 13             self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2  for self.MatPagos, self.test2  in zip(self.test2,self.MatPagos[0])]
>      14             list1.append(self.test3)
>      15             i += 1
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Esta es la función original y corre perfectamente:

```
def Savage(Acciones,MatPagos):
    test = [list(x) for x in zip(*MatPagos)]
    test2 = [max(k) for k in test]

    i = 0
    list1 = list()
    while i < len(Acciones):
        test3 = [MatPagos - test2 for MatPagos, test2 in zip(test2,MatPagos[i])]
        list1.append(test3)
        i += 1

    MatPagos = list1
```

Así es como la reescribí en una clase:

```
class savage_c(wald):
    def savage(self):
        super().getMatPagos()
        self.test = [list(x) for x in zip(*self.MatPagos)]
        self.test2 = [max(k) for k in self.test]

        i = 0
        list1 = list()
        while i < len(self.Acciones):
            self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2 for self.MatPagos, self.test2 in zip(self.test2,self.MatPagos[i])]
            list1.append(self.test3)
            i += 1

        self.MatPagos = self.list1
        print(self.MatPagos)
```

Este es el contenido de las listas:

```
print(self.MatPagos)
>>> [[200, 3200, 1800, -1800], [-1000, 2000, 5000, 3600], [-2200, 800, 3800, 6800]]
print(self.test)
>>> [[200, -1000, -2200], [3200, 2000, 800], [1800, 5000, 3800], [-1800, 3600, 6800]]
print(self.test2)
>>> [200, 3200, 5000, 6800]
```

Lo que hace la función es restar `test2` de `MatPagos` columna por columna:

`[[200 - 200, 200-(-1000), 200-(-2200)],...,[]]`

Obteniendo esta matriz

`[[0, 0, 3200, 8600], [1200, 1200, 0, 3200], [2400, 2400, 1200, 0]]`

Que estoy haciendo mal? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes usar los nombres de los atributos `self.MatPagos` y `self.test2` como variables internas en la lista por compresión. Cuando haces:

```
self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2 for self.MatPagos, self.test2 in zip(self.test2, self.MatPagos[i])]
```

Sobreescribes el valor de los atributos `self.MatPagos` y `self.test2` en la primera iteración, de forma que en la segunda iteración ambas son enteros y no las listas de listas iniciales (por lo que al hacer `self.MatPagos[i]` intentas hacer un indexado sobre un entero). Haz algo como:

```
self.test3 = [matP - test2 for matP, test2 in zip(self.test2, self.MatPagos[i])]
```

Te recomiendo que uses un `for` y no un `while` siempre que puedas, es más "pythónico" y más eficiente. Si iteras sobre todas las filas de `self.MatPagos`, sería mucho más simple y eficiente hacer simplemente:

```
def savage(self):
    self.test = [list(x) for x in zip(*self.MatPagos)]
    self.test2 = [max(k) for k in self.test]

    self.MatPagos  = [[matP - test2 for matP, test2 in zip(self.test2, mprow)]
                       for mprow in self.MatPagos]
```

Te recomiendo que te mires [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) e intentes seguir las convenciones sobre los nombres de clases/métodos/atributos. Los métodos y atributos por lo general deben empezar por minúscula y usar `_` para separar las palabras (p.e: `self.mat_pagos`), las clase deben empezar con mayúscula y usar CamelCase (p.e: `SavageC`). Son solo convenciones pero ayudan enormemente a que tu código sea más legible por terceros.

Comment: Funciono perfecto! voy a mirar la documentación Gracias!